# nodejs: можно ли создавать параметры-аннотации над методами?

Tags: node.js

Хотелось бы указывать дополнительные параметры над методами, как в php-фреймворке Symfony2 например. В виде аннотаций, в комментариях через символ @, что-нибудь в таком духе:

```
class SomeController {

    constructor() {
        //
    }

    /*
    * @Secure(roles="admin")
    * @Cache(smaxage="15")
    */
    indexAction() {
        //
    }

};
```

Есть ли какое-нибудь модули? Возможно ли это сделать как-то самому?

---

Нашел более-менее подходящее решение:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/conga-annotations

Comment: А зачем вам это?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, пишу свой фреймворк, хочется сделать его более гибким.

Comment: Вы можете оформить найденное решение как ответ на вопрос ;) Если решитесь на это не повторяйте ошибок других участников и приведите кроме ссылки хоть какое-то описание найденного решения))

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону JSDoc, он помимо простых аннотаций позволяет автоматически генерировать документацию по проекту, формат комментариев знаменит (а-ля JavaDoc) и используется в редакторах и IDE. Пример с параметрами - http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html